# Xquery if/else to dynamically namespace

Tags: namespaces, xquery

```
declare function tns:getDt($inp as xs:string) as element(ns1:Sschema)*{
  let $primary := fn-bea:get-property('PRIMARY','1')
  let $sec := fn-bea:get-property('SECONDARY','2')
  if ($primary = "1") then (
     for $response in tns:getData1()
       return
         $response  
  ) else (
  for $response in tns2:getData1()
     return
        $response   
  )
}
```

I want to call functions in different namespaces based on a weblogic admin property. A couple of questions:

1. How can i dynamically chose the namespace to use based on weblogic admin property?
2. In the above code, the Oracle workshop complains about the if/else. Can the if/else be only inside the FLWOR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question: yes, you need to add a "return" before the "if" expression to make your query syntactically valid.

Regarding your first question, I'm not really sure what's your intention?..

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with the return before the if. Regarding the first question, instead of using "1" and "2", I would like to pass in the namespace itself and use that to call the appropriate function. For example, if PRIMARY="ld:test/test1", then i want to be able to use $PRIMARY:func().

Comment: I'm sorry that’s not possible in XQuery, as namespaces need to be statically defined. This is why you'll have to use if/else or switch expressions in order to call the correct function (as you did anyway).